# Efficient Voltage Divider Battery Monitoring for 42V system

Tags: voltage-divider, power-dissipation, battery-lifespan, battery-monitor

I'm designing a system that is powered from a 10S2P LiPo battery pack and I was looking for an efficient way to monitor the battery level.
My microcontroller is 5V logic level, and I understand I can use a voltage divider circuit  to step down the voltage into a range (say 4.2V) that I can feed into the ADC on my microcontroller.
[image: 42V Voltage Divider Battery Monitor]

My main concern with this setup is the power dissipation. Although this system seems like it will work, the voltage difference is so great that I am concerned about my battery's life.

Please advise. Thanks

Circuit simulation from: [EveryCircuit](https://everycircuit.com/circuit/6618858645094400)

Comment: What is the impedance of the ADC input?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica 10k it seems. It's an Atmega 328p and from the datasheet it says _The ADC is optimized for analog signals with an output impedance of approximately 10k or less_

Comment: There are dedicated battery monitoring ic’s  that might do a more power efficient job of this, otherwise you could use a p channel fet and an npn transistor and some passives to only turn on the measurement divider when you need to make a measurement.

Comment: You can use an opamp configured as a unity gain voltage follower, they you can increase the input impedance to several hundred K depending on the opamp.

Comment: @BarnabasNomo You can monitor it with just a few microamps using a relaxation oscillator. If you want to go to a little more trouble, perhaps even less. How low do you want to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Atmega328p datasheet is pretty awful, in that it provides almost no electrical characteristics for the ADC. It does contain the ambiguous phrase " If a source with higher impedance is used, the sampling time will depend on how long
time the source needs to charge the S/H capacitor, with can vary widely", which is close to useless. Basically, they're saying that you can have a higher impedance source, but they can't be bothered to characterise it so you have to do the work - other (better) manufacturers do this for you and guarantee the results.

The way you increase the charge time is by changing ADPS2:0. The default value for this is 000, which means that the adc clock frequency is half the system clock. If you change this to 111, it divides the system clock by 128. This implies (but doesn't guarantee) that it would be ok for an input impedance of up to maybe around 640k. I would experiment with 2Mohm/200kOhm and see how it goes - my guess is that it will work pretty well (you may want to try this on a few units, and try high/low temp). Adding a small (10nF or 100nF) capacitor in parallel with the lower resistor may help (i.e. it may make it so that you dont even need to change the clock).

You can also just gate the voltage divider with the following circuit, so that it's only active when you need it to be. It seems unlikely that you need to be actively getting the battery voltage 100% of the time (you actually couln't do this even if you wanted to because it would take you at least a few CPU cycles to examing the result, since theres no comparison interrupt), so you would just enable the mosfets every few hundred ms, spend a few us getting the result, and then disable the mosfets, cutting your power consumption to almost 0. I would recommend this over an opamp, because it's cheaper, simpler, and you dont have to worry about the consumption of the opamp (you can get low power opamps, but why bother when you can just have 0 power consumption when you dont need the voltage).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7L7U7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It's also important to note that the output impedance of the circuit you posted is 9.99k, and if you used 2M/200K, it would be 181k (because thevenin)

Comment: Also note that your mosfets need to be good up to 42V (60V really, you want some margin) but the current will be very low, so you can use something like 2N7002A and MMFTP84 which are pretty cheap and plentiful

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up using an STM32 Blue Pill cos the lead time on getting the ATMEGA328's was too much. I also I experimented with using an npn bjt transistor as a switch and it seemed to do fine you can check it out here: https://everycircuit.com/circuit/6618858645094400 . I must say power electronics isn't my stronghold, so feel free to give me feedback on the design.

Comment: @BarnabasNomo so the are are two issues with your circuit: 1. your driving voltage is 3.3V, whereas the max voltage of your divider is 2.93V (42*75/1075). You're using your BJT in a common collector sort of way, so even at these low currents the low base-emitter voltage may cause an issue - it needs to be at least 0.7V. 2. the point of using a mosfet is that it acts more like a resistor, so it adds minimum distortion to your signal. A BJT will have a voltage between the collector and emitter that will also distort your signal even when driven properly.

Comment: @BarnabasNomo you can see these problems in your simulation, when you set the voltage to 42V and the output should be 2.93V, but actually its 2.67V. This problem could get worse in the real world with real transistors.

Comment: @BarnabasNomo actually, I overlooked another really obvious problem with your circuit, which is that it just flat out wont work because your base current will change the voltage across your bottom resistor anyway, resulting in a useless measurement - that current will overwhelm the voltage that you are actually trying to measure. You would need to switch the high side with a PNP BJT in order for it to work (https://tinyurl.com/27hkgtgl), which is basically the same as my circuit but with BJTs

Answer (score 1):

When the ADC does a conversion, it connects its internal sampling capacitor to the input for a certain amount of time. The minimum source impedance spec of 10k is set so this sampling capacitor charges and settles to 1LSB of the analog voltage being measured during this sampling time.

It is possible to use much larger source impedances, if you add a filter cap. This should be at least 2^n times larger than the internal sampling cap, with n being the number of bits, so when the ADC samples, voltage on the cap will drop by less than 1 LSB. Then, by not sampling too frequently, much higher impedance sources can be acquired.

The problem then, is input pin leakage current which is specified as 1µA in the datasheet. That's a very high value, and is highly suspicious. The real value is much lower, but it is not specified. For example STM32G0 specs 70nA which is a lot more usable.

So an opamp buffer could be a better option.

In addition the internal voltage reference isn't that accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Analog Specs in Microchip datasheets are always towards the end.

p.276 of 294
Analog input resistance 100 MOhm  +/- ??

Therefore you can scale both your resistor values up to 10x and not worry about leakage of 42uA.  Or scale up 30x if you prefer.